# How to Redirects with a Drop Down?

Tags: yii

I have parent page and there are two child view _sectionhead.php and _classteacher.php i need to  renderPartial to those child view when user select from dropdwon how can do this

this is my create from
[image]

IF there is any other way i like to know it.i need quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In view:**

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('some-name', "
    $('select').on('change', function (event) {
        var url = $(event.currentTarget).val();
        if (url != 0)
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
    });", CClientScript::POS_READY) ?>

<?php echo
CHtml::dropDownList("param", "select here", [
    'Select here',
    $this->createUrl('/testing/action1') => "Add class teacher",
    $this->createUrl('/testing/action2') => "Add class techer"
]) ?>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing in HTML ,Add below in HTML code

```
<option onClick="fnCallPage('classteacher')">class teacher</option>
<option onClick="fnCallPage('Section')">Section</option>
```

Add below in Javascript tag :

```
function fnCallPage(param){
//Javascript code for sending 
}
```

Comment: i appreciate this but i need to renderPartial _sectionhead.php and _classteacher.php from parent create.php i put dropdwon in create.php

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Fraz solution:

**HTML**:

```
    <option onClick="fnCallPage('_classteacher')">class teacher</option>
    <option onClick="fnCallPage('_sectionhead')">Section</option> 

    <div id="divContainerPartial"></div> <!-- View rendered container -->
```

**Javascript**:

```
    function fnCallPage(param){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('yourModel/renderPageByAjax');?>/' + param,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(html){
                $('#divContainerPartial').html(html);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('Error loading a '+param+' view.');
            }
        });

    }
```

**Controller**:

```
/**
 * @param $view String : View name to render.
 */
public function actionRenderPageByAjax($view)
{
    $params = array(); // Variables to view.

    $this->renderPartial('//myFolderView/'.$view, array(
        'params' => $params,
    ), false, true);
}
```